# How to alter drop all columns that start with a specific string using SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have 1 table with all of my user information. All information is the form of $user.name, $user.date, etc, ($user = username)

I want the user to be able to delete their account and alter the table to drop all of the columns that starts with the string of the user.

How would I do this... right now I am doing it the long way, which is still not working either.

```
            $sql = "ALTER TABLE userDatabase
        DROP COLUMN `$user.hour`,
        DROP COLUMN `$user.plannerData`,
        DROP COLUMN `$user.eventName`,
        DROP COLUMN `$user.eventStart`,
        DROP COLUMN `$user.eventEnd`,
        DROP COLUMN `$user.eventFreq`,
        DROP COLUMN `$user.eventSlide`";
```

Comment: Oh my goodness! That is horrible table design! Never use data as column names. Please change your table design.

Comment: Yes I agree with juergen .. that's a horiible design indeed!

Comment: Ah, I am new and I thought it was a step up from what I was doing before which was 1 table for every user... how would you recommend I design my table? I have many users and each user has many different attributes.

Comment: Each user is a row in the table. Add a column in the table for userID, which is the primary key. If a user is being removed, just delete that row in the table using the primary key.

Comment: And for the different attributes, create another table something like (id, user_id, attribute, value) that way any user can have as manu attributes as you want without this horrible design you did.

Comment: Thanks for the advice everyone, this is my first SQL table and I see now what I should do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Delete all that from your database.
create a table with all your necessary fields. and use code for registration.

```
INSERT INTO `usertable` (
   `username`, `hour`, `plannerdata`, `eventname`,
   `eventstart`, `eventend`, `eventfreq`, `eventslide`
) VALUES (
   'datatoenter', 'datatoenter', 'datatoenter', 'datatoenter', 
   'datatoenter', 'datatoenter', 'datatoenter', 'datatoenter'
)
```

To delete the user data, use

```
DELETE FROM `usertable` WHERE `username` = 'user'
```